# jMeter returns 401 Unauthorized error for search request

Tags: jmeter, authorization

I need to do performance testing of search in jMeter but I get 401 Unauthorized error.
Cookies are sent in request, and login seems to be successful. I ran out of ideas how to fix this.
Below I attach screenshots of my test plan and of recording from Burp.
Hope you'll help me find out the problem

[image: Login request]

[image: Login Response]

[image: Search request]

[image: Search response]

[image: Burp]

Answer (score 4):

You should be looking into "Response Data" tab of the [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener as well, "Sampler Result" doesn't tell the full story as in case of HTTP Protocol JMeter automatically considers [response status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) below 400 as successful. You will be able to ensure that you are logged in and get more information regarding this "Unauthorized" request.

I also think that you should not be seeing this `Authorization` header, if you have it hard-coded in the HTTP Header Manager - I would suggest removing it.

99.9% of failed logins are due to incorrect or missing [correlation](http://Advanced%20Load%20Testing%20Scenarios%20with%20JMeter:%20Part%201%20-%20Correlations) so please double check all the parameters, cookies and headers to detect any dynamic entities.

Comment: Thanks for help! The reason of the problem was in the wrong login request, I've sent parameters in the wrong format